# JavaScript onKeyPress assigning string

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to add an `onKeyPress` event to a dynamically created html element using JavaScript. In practise, the element is added, the id is assigned, and the `innerHTML` added, but the `onmouseover`, `onmouseout`, and `onKeyPress` (2nd last line) events are not added to the element. The last line (`.focus()`) does work.

Code:

```
function newParagraphAfter(elem)
{
blockElemId++;
newPara = document.createElement("p");
newPara.id = 'block_' + blockElemId;
newPara.contentEditable = 'true';
newPara.onmouseover = "this.style.border='1px dashed white';";
newPara.onmouseout = "this.style.border='none';";
newPara.innerHTML = "Edit Here!";
elem.parentNode.insertBefore(newPara, elem.nextSibling);
document.getElementById('block_' + blockElemId).onKeyPress = "return editKeypress(this, event)";
document.getElementById('block_' + blockElemId).focus();
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lowercase your onKeyPress and use a function

```
document.getElementById('block_' + blockElemId).onkeypress = function(e) {
    if(!e) e = event;
    return editKeypress(this, event)
};
```

Edit: Added **bobince**'s advice for a more cross-browser friendly answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon, I'd always wondered what the point of those anonymous functions was.

Comment: This will only work on IE, due to the global `window.event`. Everywhere else, the event is passed in as an argument to the handler function. You should just set `newPara.onkeypress= editKeypress`, and in `editKeypress` check for an argument. ie. traditionally: `function editKeypress(e) { if (!e) e= window.event; ...`

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can assign strings to event handlers - Javascript can coerce data but not to this degree. What you need to do instead is write you code as a function and then assign the function to the event handler